# Connect sparklyr 0.8.4 to remote spark 2.2.1 connection

Tags: r, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc, sparklyr

I'm trying to connect from R to a remote spark cluster.
The spark cluster is build on debian jessie and the R version i can install on it is at most 3.3 but I need 3.4 to be able to run FactoMineR. So I installed R on another machine and try to connect the cluster using sparklyr 0.8.4

```
> sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://spark-cluster-m:7077", spark_home="/usr/lib/spark/", version="2.2.1")
Error in start_shell(master = master, spark_home = spark_home, spark_version = version,  : 
  SPARK_HOME directory '/usr/lib/spark/' not found
```

spark isn't installed on the local machine but on the spark-cluster-m, it is :

```
jc@spark-cluster-m:/usr/lib/spark$ ls
bin  conf  data  examples  external  jars  LICENSE  licenses  NOTICE  python  R  README.md  RELEASE  sbin  work  yarn
```

Have I missed something ?
The spark cluster is on google cloud (test account) and so is the VM with R. How do I verify the port spark can be connected to ?

Thanks for your clues

@user16... You're right, this particular problem seems to be solved but my way is not ended.
I installed the same spark version (2.2.1 with hadoop > 2.7)

Here is my new error message :

```
    Error in force(code) : 
      Failed during initialize_connection: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem
            at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:91)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:524)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2516)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:137)
            at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:123)
            at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:66)
            at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:51)
            at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:4)
            at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
            at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
            at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
            at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
            at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
            at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
            at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

        Log: /tmp/RtmpTUh0z6/file5d231368db0_spark.log


    ---- Output Log ----
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processS
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
            ... 1 more
    18/07/21 18:24:59 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-cluster-m:7077...
    18/07/21 18:24:59 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark-cluster-m:7077
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
            at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
            at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
            at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
            at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:108)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark-cluster-m/10.142.0.3:7077
            at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
            at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
            at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
            at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
            at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
            ... 4 more
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: spark-cluster-m/10.142.0.3:7077
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
            at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
            ... 1 more
    18/07/21 18:25:19 ERROR StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
    18/07/21 18:25:19 WARN StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 46811.
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.142.0.5:46811
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.142.0.5, 46811, None)
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.142.0.5:46811 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.142.0.5, 46811, None)
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.142.0.5, 46811, None)
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.142.0.5, 46811, None)
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.142.0.5:4040
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
    18/07/21 18:25:19 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
    18/07/21 18:25:19 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop Unregist
```

I can see it can resolve the name (=> 10.142.0.3) 
Also, it seems to be the good port as if I use port 7000, i have the error :

```
18/07/21 18:32:54 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from spark-cluster-m/10.142.0.3:7000 is closed
18/07/21 18:32:54 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Could not connect to spark-cluster-m:7000: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
18/07/21 18:32:54 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark-cluster-m:7000
```

But I can't figure out what this means.

You say my configuration is "particular". If there is a better (and simple) approach, i would be glad to use it.

Here is how I proceeded in my tests :
I created a google dataproc cluster with spark (2.2.1)
I added Cassandra on each node

At this stage, everything works ok.

Then, i need to install FactoMineR as I'd like to try HMFA. It is said to run with R > 3.0.0 so it seems to be ok but it depends on nlme which can't be installed on R < 3.4.0 (and the one in the debian jessie backports is 3.3.)

So, what can I do ?
I must admit that i'm not very enthusiastic in restarting a full spark / cassandra cluster install from scratch...

Comment: There's a nice walkthrough of how to install R Studio on Dataproc here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-rstudio-server-on-a-cloud-dataproc-cluster. Maybe this helps give you an idea of where your approach differs?

Comment: It looks like a Spark version mismatch. Can you check if that's the case (https://radanalytics.io/howdoi/recognize-version-clash)? Also it is recommended to: 
- Update master URL
- Update dependencies POM/Gradle/Jar, so you use the same version as the cluster (http://ckl-it.de/spark-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-requirement-failed-can-only-call-getservlethandlers-on-a-running-metricssystem)